# Does the concept of sub grids in CSS Grid level 2 work in browsers now?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, subgrid

I started learning about CSS grid layout for a presentation and came across CSS grid level 2 explained in [this smashing magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/07/css-grid-2/). From here I learned about the property `sub grid`. Following point has also been noted in this article.

> Note: At the time of writing, none of the code below works in
>   browsers. The aim here is to explain the syntax and concepts. The
>   final specification is also likely to change from these details. For
>   reference, I have written this article based on the Editor’s Draft
>   available on June 23rd, 2018.

I tried searching about this topic, but failed to get proper descriptions regarding the same. Also, I couldn't find any forums to ask my doubt regarding this topic. Can anyone please help me know about this propertie's browser support? Can we start using this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the implementation status here:
https://platform-status.mozilla.org/#css-subgrids

Accordingly to the report, right now only Firefox is developing support of CSS Subgrids, although the specification is still in [Working Draft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information. Its really helpful for me and my presentation. Once again, thanks a lot....

Answer (score 0):

CSS Subgrids are not officially supported in browsers as of yet.

Firefox is due to support Subgrid in its next major release [FF71](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Release_Management/Calendar) on December 3rd 2019.

Source [Jen Simmons](https://twitter.com/jensimmons/status/1184083728865415169) (Developer at Mozilla)